# vowels-nekudos-niqqud tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-tag

I was going to tag [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10176/kubutz-and-shuruk-in-polish-hungarian-pronunciation) with something like "vowels-nekudos-niqqud" but I didn't want to create a tag that was overly specific or covered the same territory as "pronunciation".  Thoughts?

Comment: IMO it's fine. (This is too short to be an answer, else it would be.)

Comment: (A little late but...) I agree with msh210.